# C# Saving in loop error

Tags: c#, loops

I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when trying to save all items from a listbox with this method.

```
  writer = new StreamWriter(saveBox.FileName);
   foreach (var item in LstResults.Items.Cast<object>().Where(item =>  string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString())))
                    {
                        writer.Write(item.ToString().Trim() + ",");
                    }
                    writer.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong? The list is holding about 80k items.

Comment: How that is more clear than an if statement is beyond me... LINQ abuse.

Comment: @Ed it actually does look more clear to me than the equivalent `if` statement (but only slightly).

Comment: ...still don't get how ".Where(item =>  string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString())" is more clear than "if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't this be

```
item =>  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString())
```

for this loop to make sense? If you are pulling back items which have a `null` `ToString()` result, you're then calling `Trim` on a null object.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally edited yours, I'll leave my additions here :S

Answer (score 1):

The following are your suspects:

- saveBox
- item (one of the items in the ListBox)
- the result of item.ToString (very unlikely)

If any of the ListBox's items is null, you're getting an exception on that first ToString call.